# Installing vmware tools

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware

I followed exactly the case "Installing vm tools on a Ubuntu guest" from this [official page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Tools). And under usr/src/open-vm-tools-2010.06.16 I have a bunch of folders vmblock, vmci, etc.., so it seems things went ok. 
Yet after reboot of the vm the tools don't seem to be installed. An the command vmware-tooldoes not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installation, VMware tools has to be run manually. If you want to run it automatically then follow the instructions on this location.

http://www.watchingthenet.com/how-to-automatically-start-vmware-tools-in-ubuntu-and-kubuntu.html

Answer (score 1):

try to install this package:

```
sudo apt install open-vm-tools
```

work perfect for me in Ubuntu